# A second operation started on DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a background task that runs every few seconds in my ASP.NET Core application. It returns the following error:

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'ThaiLiveApi.Data.DataContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. 
This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.
```

I would think because im using the dbcontext in scoped that this would not be possible and only use one dbcontext for that scope. Am I missing something?

Here is my worker code:

```
    public class FacebookWorker : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        private readonly ILogger<FacebookWorker> _logger;

        public FacebookWorker(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ILogger<FacebookWorker> logger)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        private readonly int JobIntervalInSecs = 5;
        private Timer _timer;


        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            // Invoke the DoWork method every 5 seconds. 
            _timer = new Timer(callback: async o => await DoWork(o),
                state: null, dueTime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(JobIntervalInSecs));
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task DoWork(object state) {
            // allow only a certain number of concurrent work. In this case, 
            // only allow one job to run at a time. 
            if (State.numberOfActiveJobs < State.maxNumberOfActiveJobs) {
                // Update number of running jobs in one atomic operation. 
                try {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref State.numberOfActiveJobs);
                    _logger.LogInformation("Fetching comments " + DateTime.Now);
                    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
                        var facebookService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFacebookService>();
                        await facebookService.FetchAndHandleComments();
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref State.numberOfActiveJobs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose I'm getting this error because of my Worker? Is it possible this is caused in another part of my code?

Comment: How are you registering the data context dependency?

Comment: The datacontext is registered this way in the startup

`services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostGresql")));`

Comment: are you using dispose for the db context pattern something like repository unit of work pattern will solve the problem if i understand well

Comment: Should I use dispose when my service that's using the dbcontext is scoped?

Comment: And, probably stating the obvious, the service is also scoped?

Comment: The service is scoped indeed

Comment: `callback: async o => await DoWork(o)` is an async void (fire and forget). Use an event handler instead.  Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense! I wouldn't know how else to use the timer in my background worker, do you have any suggestion @Nkosi?

Comment: I don't have this problem when I'm using sqlite, is this due to sqlite only allows one write per time?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when a process started but last process is not complete. try to use using block when call DbContext. One more thing Check your DbContext instance is it static or not.

Comment: My context is definitely not static and in the worker I do use the using block.